# How dynamically Parse JSON in Go?

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

So I have some problem with Parsing a JSON file in Go. I already try a lot of way how to work around but i dont seems find the solution.

So let say i have some JSON file that looks like this

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 201,
            "name": "Nulla",
            "price": 207,
            "categoryId": 1,
            "rate": 2.44,
            "content": "Culpa sed tenetur incidunt quia veniam sed molliti",
            "review": 78,
            "imageUrl": "https://dummyimage.com/400x350"
        },
        {
            "id": 202,
            "name": "Corporis",
            "price": 271,
            "categoryId": 1,
            "rate": 2.18,
            "content": "Nam incidunt blanditiis odio inventore. Nobis volu",
            "review": 67,
            "imageUrl": "https://dummyimage.com/931x785"
        },
        {
            "id": 203,
            "name": "Minus",
            "price": 295,
            "categoryId": 1,
            "rate": 0.91,
            "content": "Quod reiciendis aspernatur ipsum cum debitis. Quis",
            "review": 116,
            "imageUrl": "https://dummyimage.com/556x985"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to parse it Dynamically (without making the struct for it). I already try with `map[string]interface{}` way but it doesnt work. I already try another 3rd party lib called jsoniter but it doesn't work too.

The only way that i can make it "somehow" work is to try wrap the json_string with bracket
`[jsonstring]`

Here's my code.

```golang
file, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("p1.json")
var results []map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal(file, &results)
fmt.Printf("%+v", results) // Output []
```

Comment: always check errors `json.Unmarshal(file, &results)`

Comment: You should be able to unmarshal that JSON into `map[string]interface{}` (not `[]map[string]interface{}`). When you say it didn't work, what happened? You should check all returned errors. Are you sure it's reading the file correctly?

Comment: I'm really sry. I'm new to Go and just trying new things. Thanks for the feedbacks. I'll make sure to check error in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always check errors. Checking the error from `json.Unmarshal` you can see this:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []map[string]interface {}
```

You are using a slice of maps `[]map[string]interface{}` to marshal to, instead of what you want, a map:

```
// var results []map[string]interface{} // bad-type
var results map[string]interface{} // correct-type
err := json.Unmarshal(body, &results)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("%+v", results) // Output [map[categoryId:1 content:Culpa sed tenetur incidunt quia veniam sed molliti id:20 ...
```

https://play.golang.org/p/4OpJiNlB27f